# How to use if statement in an array?

Tags: php, array

Firstly sorry for my English. I hope you understand me.

I have an array like this:

```
$fields =  array(
  'author' => '<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="author" name="author" type="text" placeholder="Name '.( $req ? '*' : '' ) .'" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" ' . $aria_req . ' /></div>',
  'email'  => '<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail '.( $req ? '*' : '' ) .'" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></div>',
  'url'  => '<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="url" name="url" type="text" placeholder="Website '.( $req ? '*' : '' ) .'" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></div>',
);
```

I want the use if statement inside this array. Like this:

```
$fields =  array(
   'author' => '<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="author" name="author" type="text" placeholder="Name '.( $req ? '*' : '' ) .'" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" ' . $aria_req . ' /></div>',
   'email'  => '<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail '.( $req ? '*' : '' ) .'" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></div>',
   if($showURL==1){'url'  => '<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="url" name="url" type="text" placeholder="Website '.( $req ? '*' : '' ) .'" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></div>'},
);
```

I'm trying this but it is shows a syntax error:

```
$fields =  array(
    'author' => '<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="author" name="author" type="text" placeholder="Adınız '.( $req ? '*' : '' ) .'" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" ' . $aria_req . ' /></div>',
    'email'  => '<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-posta adresiniz '.( $req ? '*' : '' ) .'" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></div>',
       (($showURL==1) ?  'url'  => '<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="url" name="url" type="text" placeholder="Website '.( $req ? '*' : '' ) .'" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></div>' : '' ) ,
);
```

I'm getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in C:\wamp\www\blabla\comments.php on line 62

How can I use this if statement inside this array? Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Omer

```
$fields =  array(
    'author' => '<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="author" name="author" type="text" placeholder="Name '.( $req ? '*' : '' ) .'" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" ' . $aria_req . ' /></div>',
    'email'  => '<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail '.( $req ? '*' : '' ) .'" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></div>',
);

if($showURL == 1) {
    $fields['url'] = '<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="url" name="url" type="text" placeholder="Website '.( $req ? '*' : '' ) .'" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></div>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Alex! This is exactly the solution I'm looking for. You've made me very happy.

Comment: Glad it has helped. It's fairly basic PHP array code so hopefully you can see that we are adding a new item to the array if `$showURL` is 1 (you can also use `if($showURL) {` or `if($showURL == true) {`. Have a look here if you want to read more: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp

Comment: I think there are hundreds more things to learn. :) I will definitely check the source you suggest. Thank you very much again Alex.